# How to send response payload body from ADF web activity to logic apps

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I have a web activity in my data factory pipeline. I use that for  POST request to an API. The response payload to that POST request can sometimes contain errors. If there are errors, I need to email these errors to someone. So I created a logic app and added that to the pipeline in ADf that shoots an email every time I run the pipeline. I have two questions,

1. In the body of the email I am able to send pipeline run details, is there any way I can send the response payload to the logic app to add that in the email body?
2. Is there a way we can customize the pipeline to call the logic app only if the response payload contains errors?

Appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Provided your endpoint returns JSON object <4MB then you should be able to use the following in the Body of your logic app POST.
`@activity('your web activity').output.yourJSONkey`

You can use ADF functions to see if the response contains an error message (but that's not the same as getting an error response code from the endpoint) e.g. if your response contains a key named `error` you can identify it with
`@contains(@activity('your web activity').output,'error')`